# Is it possible that browser's rendering mode dynamically change from standard to quirks

Tags: cross-browser, standards-compliance, quirks-mode

Suppose that you have a page that renders in browser's standard rendering mode. Suppose that there is a button on the page that, when clicked, downloads a set of external CSS and JavaScript files and creates some DOM elements.

Is it possible that after the button is pressed and new CSS and JavaScript is downloaded and new DOM created, that the rendering mode for the page changes from standard to quirks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: I have no idea.

Long answer: You might be able to take advantage of browser-specific "features" and convince the browser to change from standards to quirks, but it would likely involve some nasty hacks and unmaintainable coding practices. The W3C has an interface called `DOMImplementation` ([link to specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-102161490)) that adds some document-level functions to DOM2, but as far as how effective they are I can't say.

However, the key point of this answer is that you should question exactly why you need quirks mode in the first place. Ideally, you should create your new DOM elements to be compatible with standards mode and avoid the whole mess altogether. Considering that quirks mode can vary greatly between browsers, your best bet is to target the standard and handle inconsistencies on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Hey hey Eric, thanks for the answer. Actually, I don't need quirks mode. I'm creating a web widget that is embedded in host pages in the similar fashion as google maps do. The widget must not change the host page in any way, that is why I was worried that for example an invalid DOM or some error that my widget my have could make the browser fall from standards to quirks mode.

I believe that it is not possible for that to happen, but wanted to check with someone who knows that for sure.